# Docker Enviroment Variable not working?

Tags: command-line, dockerfile

I am having issues append an environment variable in my Dockerfile to the ENTRYPOINT.

Due to the Dockerfile having sensitive data I will try and show a similar example:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
.
.
.
ENV test_var hello

ENTRYPOINT ["keyword"] 

CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo $test_var"]
```

I got the CMD execution from:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd and
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5509

In my mind, when running:

```
sudo docker run -it nameOfImage
```

keyword should be executed with $test_var being appended. Either of the following two should work:

```
keyword $test_var

keyword hello
```

However it is just not working for me. The environment variable is subsituting correctly when using RUN:

```
RUN echo $test_var
```

However, CMD fails to work with it. Any suggestions? Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Dockerfile will allow you to perform the substitution in this way, however there is a workaround by passing a shell script to the ENTRYPOINT.

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV test_var hello
COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["test_var"]
```

*entrypoint.sh*

```
#/bin/bash
echo $(printenv $1) #in this case 'echo' is 'keyword'
```

You'll see the result

```
hello
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I should have clarified that "keyword" is an executable for a program if that makes a difference. Would doing it this way be the same as: sudo docker run -it nameOfImage paramater1 parameter2?

Comment: If you would like to just simply print the value of an environment variable like test_var, you can do `sudo docker run nameOfImage printenv test_var`. Assuming you're still using a Dockerfile, you'd only need the FROM and ENV lines of my Dockerfile for this to work. If you'd like to use the Dockerfile I posted in full but want to print the value of a different variable, you can do `sudo docker run nameOfImage <variable_name>`.